# wildcard in bigquery load from gs

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to load many parquet files from Google Storage into Bigquery.

The file format is

`gs://abc/date=2018-01-01/*.parquet`

Where every date folder has 1 file, but I have many date folders

When I try to use

`gs://abc/date=2018-*/*.parquet`

I get an error about files not found.

I am doing this via the UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use only one wildcard character.
If the filename is same everywhere you can use

```
gs://abc/date=2018-*/<filename>.parquet
```

More here [wildcard characters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#load-wildcards)